# Using computed and composables in vue 3.2 with the setup script tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently trying out some of the latest vue version and features (3.2).

I've created a useFetch composable to reuse some logic (it's based on the vue [documentation](https://staging.vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#async-state-example))

**useFetch.js**

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 10000,
});

export function useFetch(url) {
    const data = ref(null);
    const error = ref(null);
    const isLoading = ref(true);

    apiClient({ method, url, data: body })
        .then((response) => (data.value = response.data))
        .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
        .finally(() => isLoading.value = false)

  return { data, error }
}
```

I'm using the useFetch composable in a component to fetch companies from the backend. The data I'm getting back is rough so I want to reformat it using a computed (That was the way I did it when using vue 2)

**CompanyList.vue**

```html
<script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue';
    import useFetch from '@/composables/useFetch';
    import { formatEmail, formatPhone, formatEnterpriseNumber } from '@/utils/formatters';

    const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch('get', '/companies');

    const companies = computed(() =>
        data.companies?.map((company) => ({
            id: `#${company.id}`,
            name: `${company.legal_entity_type} ${company.business_name}`,
            enterprise_number: formatEnterpriseNumber(company.enterprise_number),
            email: formatEmail(company.email),
            phone: formatPhone(company.phone),
        }))
    );
</script>

<template>
    <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-else-if="error">Oops! Error encountered: {{ error }}</div>
    <div v-else-if="companies">
        Companies:
        <pre>{{ companies }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No data :(</div>
</template>
```

When using `Companies` inside the template tags it stays `null`. I've checked and `data` has a companies property of the type Array with data in it.

Anyone an idea how to handle this?

Comment: Should be reading the inner value `data.value.companies?.map(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue may be due to use of `ref`. Try using `reactive` for data instead of `ref`

```js
export function useFetch(url) {
    const data = reactive(null);
    const error = ref(null);
    const isLoading = ref(true);

    apiClient({ method, url, data: body })
        .then((response) => (data = response.data))
        .catch((err) => (error.value = err))
        .finally(() => isLoading.value = false)

  return { data, error }
}
```

To use `ref`, you would need to access the value via `ref.value`. Also, `ref` is not the best choice for objects and arrays as it was meant for primitive data types. to use `ref` you can

```js
const companies = computed(() =>
  data.value?.companies?.map((company) => ({
    id: `#${company.id}`,
    name: `${company.legal_entity_type} ${company.business_name}`,
    enterprise_number: formatEnterpriseNumber(company.enterprise_number),
    email: formatEmail(company.email),
    phone: formatPhone(company.phone),
  }))
);
```

note the use of `?.` after value, which is required since the ref is null initially.

Comment: Oops indeed. I forgot the .value part but I will change my useFetch to use reactive instead of ref. Thanks!